# Are there any forward error correcting code algorithms for a partially reliable channel?

Tags: algorithm, ecc

There are plenty or practical FEC algorithms - RS, Golay, convolutional codes of all sorts. All of them assume that the original data and the FEC code are sent over the same channel with the same error rate. Are there any algorithms where the size of the error correction code can be reduced, assuming that the code is sent over a separate reliable channel?

Say, we have two communication channels. One "cheap" with good throughput, but the channel can have bit errors, and the second "expensive" channel, with smaller throughput but absolutely reliable - a channel that has no bit errors of any kind.

Most FEC algorithms assume that errors are distributed uniformly - both in original message and in ECC code and account for that. For example, Golay24 doubles the message size but operates under the assumption that error bits can happen in both original message and in golay code. Are there any algorithms that generate shorter ECC code with assumption that it would always be transmitted correctly?

Comment: If the original data and FEC code are sent over two communication channels, would there be an issue in trying to align the two channels in the receiver?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really an EE subject (given that there are likely other SE sites that would be more suited). I'm prepared to be persuaded otherwise of course.

Comment: I've did a search first. There are plenty of questions answers about FEC on EE SE, some much more technical with 2K views like https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282479/fec-limit-ber-in-communication-systems . Please do suggest an appropriate SE site for this.

Comment: @AndreyL yes I understand and, maybe that question should also be considered for closure.

Comment: yes, there absolutely are codes that do not assume uniform error probability.

Comment: If you rephrase the question as to how to best design FEC for two channels with differing BER then this is clearly EE (well it is taught in the specialization subjects in an EE degree). I think the answer is no as the good channel doesn't really tell you any extra information as to the location of the errors in the bad channel. I suspect the best you can do is to send the most valuable data over the good channel and design the best FEC you can for the bad.  If all traffic bits are equally valuable I don't think you can do much.

Comment: @Marcus Müller , Thanks a lot, "non-uniform" is indeed a keyword. Searching by bthis keyword results instantly pop up - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4051515_Results_on_Non-Uniform_Error_Correction_Using_Low-Density_Parity-Check_Codes

Answer (score 1):

No, because the point of the FEC is to increase the reliability of an otherwise unreliable communications link.

Within engineering, FEC is intended for actual communications links and those have points of failure within them, they are always unreliable to some degree. Within that context, an 'absolutely reliable' communications link does not exist, it will always have failure modes. So the system you describe cannot be built.

To be honest, the question reads like an exploration of a hypothesis rather than a practical engineering question.

Comment: No, this is a very practical question. We do have two noisy communication channels, both over the same medium. One channel has no error protection at all, another already has a rather strong error protection in place (variant of turbo codes with RS on top). Obviously, the second channel is not a 100% reliable link, but it behaves like one - either it corrects the message entirely, or it just dies if the error rate is too high. My goal is to get something in the middle combining the two - by putting ECC code into "reliable" channel, but not wasting the precious capacity of this second channel.

Comment: @AndreyL, *"Say, we have two communication channels...And the second "expensive" channel, with smaller throughput but absolutely reliable - a channel that has NO bit errors of any kind."* No, that isn't practical. Note your heavy emphasis on the reliable ('absolutely') and 'NO'. Now your last comment suddenly tries to contradict those requirements you stated. It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and the answer is to that question: what you describe can't be built.

Comment: Sorry, NO. It is existing practical channel - it gets the message reliably (or not gets it at all). This is a practical working system, the design of which I can't change - I'm getting two data packets at a time - one with bit errors and one without. I've asked if there is an efficient ECC algorithm for this setup. Following your logic nothing can be built at all and there is no way to ensure data integrity - all hashes have a chance of collision (1/2^128) for common algorithms, but still. Really???

Comment: @AndreyL, it's your logic. Let's start from the beginning with your words: *"Say, we have two communication channels...And the second "expensive" channel, with smaller throughput but absolutely reliable - a channel that has NO bit errors of any kind."* 'Absolutely reliable' and 'NO bit errors of any kind', right? Your words.

Comment: In the context of a "practical engineering question," a channel with an error rate of (say) 1 in 2^256 is the same thing as a channel with an error rate of exactly 0. To me, it doesn't make sense to claim that the question is not a practical engineering question on the basis that it has a theoretical flaw that will never occur in practice.